# How to Recursively Delete the Files with Specific Extension

Tags: c#, .net

I am using the Following Code to delete the Files with Specific extension

```
private void deleteFilesFromLocalDirectory() {
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"Z:\Doku\Instructions\");
    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.odt").Where(p => p.Extension == ".odt").ToArray();
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        try
        {
            file.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
            File.Delete(file.FullName);
        }
        catch { }
}
```

I have many Folders inside the Instructions and I want my code to go to each and every folder inside the Instructions and delete the files with **".odt" extensions**. Currently my code is only deleting the ".odt" files on the location which I am providing i.e. (Z:\Doku\Instructions)

i want my code to delete **".odt"** Files from all the folders inside the **Instructions**

Comment: One of the overloads of GetFiles has a SearchOption that can instuct it to search all subdirectories

Comment: @Crowcoder Can you post your solution?

Comment: Out of curiosity why the double check? `GetFiles("*.odt").Where(p => p.Extension == ".odt")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overload of the `Directory.GetFiles` API that accepts an `SearchOption` that lets you specify that you want search the current dictionary and all its subdirectories.

It returns a `string[]` so you should modify your current a bit:

```
private void deleteFilesFromLocalDirectory()
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"Z:\Doku\Instructions\", "*.odt",
        System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (string file in files)
        try
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }
        catch { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is always a good idea to [check the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-6.0#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_) for the APIs you are using. You can use this overload to search all nested folders. And you don't need the `Where` clause since you are already specifying the extension.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("your path here", "*.odt", System.IO.SearchOptions.AllDirectories).ToArray();
```

You can also manually [recurse through folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-iterate-through-a-directory-tree)

Comment: it is not working

Comment: After Providing the path it shows Error on whole line

Comment: @Muhammadzubair I just made an edit. I left some of your code in my snippet but the GetFiles I am using returns a string array, not FileInfo. Try this update?